# My pytorch is not able to install in my python environment what should i do?

Tags: python, python-3.9

[Error i am having if anyonce could help thanks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEdMB.jpg)

i was trying to download pytorch==1.4.0 but its getting error that my python 3.9 version is not compatible.

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: You are correct. That version of PyTorch is not compatible with that version of Python. You'll need to either use an earlier version of Python (3.8 or earlier) or a later version of PyTorch.

Comment: Thank you and i will edit the question later on if that different version didnt work and will write it with the full data.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. It didn't work for me, only after I downloaded Conda.

step 1: go to: https://www.anaconda.com/

Note: conda is a handy toolkit you should consider downloading

step 2: run this command in command prompt (admin)

```
conda create --name name_me_whatever_u_want

conda activate name_me_whatever_u_want
```

What this command does is it sets up an environment.

step 3: You go to this website and select the best for you, but remember, the package should be conda, not pip.
step 4: Copy the link you got from that website, mine was:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

and that I hope this fixes your problem